# one to one relationship, ASP.NET MVC and referential integrity error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys

I've searched many posts and learned that this is one of the ways setting up one to one relationship in EF, but seems like editing doesn't work very well.

```
public class Employee
{        
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int WorkingDateTimeId { get; set; }  
    public virtual WorkingDateTime WorkingDateTimes { get; set; } 

}

public class WorkingDateTime
{          
    [ForeignKey("Employees")] 
    public int WorkingDateTimeId { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }

}
```

When I create, it creates. But WorkingDateTimeId property in Employee entity is always 0.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkingDateTimes.Day, "Monday: ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.WorkingDateTimes.Day, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control time_element" } }) 
        </div>
    </div>
```

When editing, I get this error:
 **A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Employee.EmpId' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'WorkingDateTime.WorkingDateTimeId' on the other end.**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmpId,Name,WorkingDateTimes")] Employee employee)
    {

        db.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified; // causing problem here
    }
```

Is my one to one relationship wrong? What needs to be done to edit it properly and saves in db? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key definitions are wrong.
WorkingDateTimeId is the primary key of the WorkingDateTime table, it is NOT a ForeignKey to it. The ForeignKey key from WorkingDateTime to Employee is EmpId.

```
public class Employee
{        
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
    public virtual WorkingDateTime WorkingDateTimes { get; set; } 
}

public class WorkingDateTime
{          
    [Key]
    public int WorkingDateTimeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employees")]
    public int EmpId {get;set;}
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
}
```

This would also be correct

```
public class Employee
{        
    [Key]
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WorkingDateTimes")]
    public int WorkingDateTimeId { get; set; }  
    public virtual WorkingDateTime WorkingDateTimes { get; set; } 
}

public class WorkingDateTime
{          
    [Key] 
    public int WorkingDateTimeId { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What happens? Errors are needed.